# Kernel module, multiple high resolution timers

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I want to implement multiple hrtimers, but I'm not sure how to use all of them with same callback function. For example I have array of type my_struct where one of the field is a struct hrtimer.

When I enter the callback function how to determine which element of the array is calling it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [container_of](http://www.kroah.com/log/linux/container_of.html) macro:

```c
struct my_struct {
    int my_something;
    struct hrtimer my_timer;
    ...
};

enum hrtimer_restart my_callback(struct hrtimer *hrtimer)
{
    struct my_struct my = container_of(hrtimer, struct my_struct, my_timer);
    my->my_something = 42;
    ...
}
```